# Get rid of "ArrayOf" prefix when serializing a collection in C#

Tags: c#

I have a WebMethod which return a collection of PackageItemField:

```
[WebMethod]        
public List<PackageItemField> GetAvailablePackges()
{
    ... ;
}
```

What i get :

```
<ArrayOfPackageItemField xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <PackageItemField name="a">1</PackageItemField>
  <PackageItemField name="b">2</PackageItemField>
</ArrayOfPackageItemField>
```

What i need : Personalize the root element name

```
<SomeThingElse>
  <PackageItemField name="a">1</PackageItemField>
  <PackageItemField name="b">2</PackageItemField>
</SomeThingElse>
```

Solution which is not suitable for me :
encapsulate the collecction as property inside a new class and use the follwing attributs

```
public class ClassTest
{
    private List<PackageItemField> coll;

    [XmlArray("SomeThingElse")]
    [XmlArrayItem("PackageItemField")]
    public List<PackageItemField> Coll
    {
        get
        {
            return coll;
        }
        set
        {
            coll = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Why not :
because i'll have a root node as ClassTest int output.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Asawyer don't forgot that most of those attribut are applied to property not to WebMethod.

Comment: is there any solution can help me to do this ?????????

Answer (score 1):

Is this more what you had in mind?

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

public class TestService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [return: XmlArray("MyArray")]
    [return: XmlArrayItem("MyItem")]
    public List<string> HelloWorld()
    {
        return new List<string>() { "Hello World" };
    }
}
```

SOAP 1.2 response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <HelloWorldResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <MyArray>
        <MyItem>string</MyItem>
        <MyItem>string</MyItem>
      </MyArray>
    </HelloWorldResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Comment: @Etienne In the "What I need" section he is showing he needs to rename the outputted xml elements. That's exactly what these attributes control.

Answer (score -1):

To get rid of the generated ArrayOf, you can use [[XmlElement]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_2)